# How to css query an html string without appending it to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to apply css queries to an html string returned from the server on the frontend without causing any side effects (scripts being executed in the background, attempts at retrieving imgs from relative urls on the site, etc.). A previous StackOverflow post suggested the following JQuery for parsing an html document then querying with css:

```
  var html = $('<html/>').html(cur_html).contents();
  // queries can then be done on html
```

I'm using google.com as a test site but JQuery will attempt to download images and run its script tags since its being added to the DOM. Unfortunately, for my app I will need those tags intact so merely removing them would defeat the purpose. To top it off this also removes html, head, and body as mentioned in other related SO posts.

My goal is to just filter that string for outerHTML similar to beautifulsoup with its css queries and perhaps obtain some attributes along the way -- all without side effects. Am I missing a hidden function in JQuery? or is there another library that acts closer to beautifulsoup in javascript?

Comment: so alter the src attributes so they do not have the values or set them to data-src.

Comment: @epascarello I should have been more specific about my goal. I will need the source entirely intact, one reason is because I will need those src attributes later. I could try and maintain the state of each tag's src attribute manually (and all other side effect surprises I happen to not have realized when adding elements to a DOM), but I'm looking for a cleaner solution that wouldn't require the DOM at all or any library/JQuery way to deal with the DOM without the side effects.